# Edit a number gsm on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to edit a number gsm which is in my page home.blade.php in the folder "view" in using a EDIT system. The number is **0101 41 78 03** below

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs" style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p>blablablalblalblablalablblalblblbalbalbalbalbalbablablablabalbalbalbalbal</p>
    <span style="font-size: 18px;color: #0d3863;font-weight: bold;">0101 41 78 03</span>
 </div>
```

In the folder routes I have that:

```
Route::get('/home', function(){
  return view('home');
});

Route::PATCH('/update/{id}','AdminController@update');
```

In my Controller named AdminController I only have that:

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $gsm = Gsm::find($id);
  return view('gsm.edit', compact('gsm'));    
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $request->validate([
   'number_gsm' => 'required'
  ]);
  $gsm = Gsm::find($id);
  $gsm->number_gsm = $request->get('number_gsm');
  $gsm->save();
  return redirect()->route('gsm.index')
                   ->with('success', 'updated successfully');    
}
```

Now I have a matter in my folder view => gsm => I have 2 files index.blade.php and edit.blade.php

In index.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number Gsm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  @foreach($numbers as $number)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$number->number_gsm}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('gsm.edit',$number->id)}}">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

And edit.blade.php I have

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('gsm.update',$number->id)}}" method="POST">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
  @csrf
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="form-group-input-1">Number GSM</label>
    <input type="text" name="number_gsm" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$number->number_gsm}}">
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">MAJ</button>
  </form>
```

I will wish display the number 0101 41 78 03 in the page index.blade.php with a button edit and the change. For now my two pages are empty. (index.blade.php and edit.blade.php)

I am really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**edit.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::model($number, ['route' => ['gsm.update', $number->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post','files'=>true]) !!}

  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
            @csrf
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label for="form-group-input-1">Number GSM</label>

             {!! Form::text("number_gsm", old("number_gsm"), ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'GSM Number']) !!}
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">MAJ</button>



{!! Form::close() !!}
```